# Visual Studio 2017 RC - Can't make a new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to make a new project in Visual Studio 2017

[image]

and when i fill path, project name, etc and click ok, I get a message

[image]

I tried to add permission for Administrator/ Autentification users/ Users and nothing happened. Always I had a same message. I can open existing project, but I can't make a new one.

Comment: Did you also try running as a local administrator?

Comment: can you change path to project?

Comment: Do you run Avira Antivirus? There are lots of issues with Avira and Development Environment - Android Studio has similar problems when you enable the jack Compiler.
I needed to put my temp folder with a mask (in your case likely ``*.2mb``) on the exceptions list of Avira. Same for visualstudio.exe and studio64.exe (android). Then it worked.

Comment: No, I dont have Avira antivirus, i use eset nod 32. I try to pauze protection, but i still can not create a project. I reinstall complete Visual Studio, but guess what happened, I still can not create any type of project.. :(

Comment: @Nemanja

Your installation of VS RC is doubtful. Install VS 2017 since now it is released.